# How to pass variable number of arguments to lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda

I am trying to pass variable number of arguments to a lambda function. what is the prototype to accept variable number of arguments in lambda functions? should i write a named function instead of lambda?

```
std::once_flag flag;

template<typename ...Args>
void gFunc(Args... args)
{
}

template<typename ...Args>
void func(Args... args)
{
    std::call_once(flag,[](/*accept variable number of arguments*/... args)
                        {
                                // more code here
                                gFunc( args...);
                        }, 
                        args...
                        );
}
```

the below signatures give error:

```
[&](){ }
[&args](){ }
[&args...](){ }
[&,args...](){ }
[&...args](){ }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
template<typename ...Args>
void func(Args... args)
{
    std::call_once(flag,[&, args...]( )
                        {   
                         gFunc( args...);
                        }, 
                        args...
                        );
}
```

Stolen from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

> **§ 5.1.2** A capture followed by an ellipsis is a pack expansion (14.5.3).

```
[ Example:
template<class... Args>
void f(Args... args) {
auto lm = [&, args...] { return g(args...); };
lm();
}
—end example ]
```

Comment: If the argument pack is expanded, how can we access the argument pack again? [This](http://ideone.com/rwbzq9) signature does not work.

Comment: @ProgramCpp It works with [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b83cb856787c83a3) and [gcc 4.9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a1a6a2da4b2881f)

Comment: Thank you :) I would like to pass only args by value `[args...](){gFunc(args...);};`

Answer (score 11):

In C++14 you can do

```
auto lambda = [](auto... args) {...};
```

But in your case I believe simple capture is enough:

```
std::call_once(flag, [&] {
                         gFunc(args...); // will implicitly capture all args
                     }
               );
```

Comment: @ProgramCpp works wit[gcc 4.9 and clang 3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29c9e344e1d7cafe)

Comment: how would you access the arguments inside your `auto lambda = [][auto... args) { ... };`